# Should we allow touches of humor in questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Occasionally I'll add touches of humor to my question, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271961/is-there-anything-bad-about-having-multiple-imports-on-one-line). If you didn't catch it, I added `doge` and `cheese` to the list of imports. This is what I consider "touches of humor". Some people could have a little laugh at it, others might frown upon it. My simple question is, should we allow this? Is it okay in general, or is it generally frowned upon?

Comment: Every site builds its own culture. You should ask this on the per-site meta to the site in question as each site could have a different take

Comment: If you have to explain the joke...

Comment: Related discussion in MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding the question of yours that you linked to. That is totally acceptable. It can be kind of boring to read *foo* and *bar* and *foobar* all the time, and your *doge* and *cheese* doesn't negatively effect the question's understanding or anything.

---

**On a more general note:**
You can include anything in your post that you want, but be aware, that extra fluff *(pointless remarks)* , *salutations*, etc, could possibly cause you to receive a downvote or two from users. And the chances are pretty good that someone will come along and edit your post removing the unnecessary things, and/or making things more readable.

***As long as the humor doesn't make the question/answer difficult to understand or add much more to read, I don't mind.***

Some of the highest upvoted posts are full of humor and story telling.

**Probably the best example of efficient story telling, with some subtle humor is this answer by Jacob Swartwood - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472397/3041194.** See how the story telling and subtle humor does not take away from meaning or make things complicated, but actually makes the answer easier to understand.

---

*Kind of unrelated, but if you want to laugh, read the answers to this question - [What code would you have on your wedding cake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake). But don't go asking a question like that in this day in age, or you'd likely receive 40 downvotes and a closed question, which in turn could lead to a question ban.*

---

Also, there are many different cultures of people that use SO. So what one culture finds funny, other cultures may not *get the joke*, or possibly even find the joke *offensive*.

Comment: So, as always, cautious editing judgement, and cultural sensitivity.  Maybe also providing links to reference texts, like knowyourmeme?